# Adding two TokenStream streams together (an ASCIIFoldingFilter case)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I wrote a custom analyzer that uses ASCIIFoldingFilter in order to reduce the extended Latin set in location names to the regular Latin.

```
public class LocationNameAnalyzer extends Analyzer    {

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String arg0, Reader reader) {

        //TokenStream result = new WhitespaceTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);
        StandardTokenizer tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);

        TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(tokenStream);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);

        result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);


        return result;
    }

}
```

I know it is full of deprecated stuff, as it is now, but that I will correct later on. My problem right now is that when I apply this analyzer, I am able to find results using standard Latin, but not when searching for the name in original.

For example: "Munchen" brings me results related to Munich, but "München" does not anymore.

I assume that in my case, the ASCIIFoldingFilter simply overrides the characters in my stream, so the question is how to add the two streams together (the normal one, and the folded Latin one)

Comment: hi! Could you add library versions and imports?

Answer (score 2):

You should use your filter both on the Analyzer and on the Searcher, in that way the tokens used to search will be the same as the ones stored on the index.